# Security Issue while using js amcharts with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, amcharts

Using js amcharts with PHP, Found that source code and paths  is accessible through charts. How to block it as this can be serious security issue. I am new to PHP, please elaborate the answer if possible. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is a server side language [amcharts.js](https://www.amcharts.com/javascript-charts/) runs on the client, meaning any data it receives must be accessible to the same client that is rendering the chart.  You can't make data visible to the cart but invisible to the user, however if you want to limit what the user can see you can render the chart data as JSON in the containing html page (using [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)) and then pass it as a variable to the charting library, such as:

```
<script>
  var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
   "type": "serial",
   "theme": "light",
   "marginRight": 70,
   "startDuration": 1,
   "graphs": [{
     "balloonText": "<b>[[category]]: [[value]]</b>",
     "fillColorsField": "color",
     "fillAlphas": 0.9,
     "lineAlpha": 0.2,
     "type": "column",
     "valueField": "visits"
   }],
   "chartCursor": {
     "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
     "cursorAlpha": 0,
     "zoomable": false
   },
   "categoryField": "country",
   "categoryAxis": {
     "gridPosition": "start",
     "labelRotation": 45
   },
   "export": {
     "enabled": true
   }
   "dataProvider": <%php echo json_encode($ResultsArray); %>
  });
</script>
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```